# How can I add a field only if it is completed?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a site:

[link](http://www.dg-design.ch/design-4-good/)

In this page you will find a link that says "website", this link is complete administration panel.

The problem is that not all companies have websites, and then the field must remain free.

If the administration panel, the field remains empty ... the site use the word "website" and is a link in a new tab by current page.

I put an image to understand better.

[image]

To see what happens ... click on the word website at "BSL-Student Council".

I use Wordpress and Custom Fields plugin.

I put and **PHP** code for this section

```
<div class="vright">

                    <p><?php echo substr(get_the_content(),0,300); ?></p>

                    <?php $web = types_render_field("value_website", array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";"));

                    $strin = "<a target='_blank' href=\"".$web."\">Website</a>";

                    echo $strin; ?>

                </div>
```

You can help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I received a suggestion and tried, below is the code but still does not work

```
<?php $web = types_render_field("value_website", array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";"));

            if (isset($web)) {
              $strin = "<a target='_blank' href=\"".$web."\">Website</a>";
                echo $strin;
                }

                     ?>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add link of your website.

Comment: I am not sure how the logic can be applied in `php` but you can just try with an `if` statement and check if your `$.web` has value and place the element inside the `if`

Comment: Sorry,I edit my post.now it`s ok

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I edited my post, so you mean?

Comment: Something like that but am not sure how you have to do in `php`

Comment: And the branch else ... how should I think? How do I remove your link

Comment: Anyoane have a ideea?

Comment: @cristi - check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explaining `if (isset($web) && $web != "")`:

- `isset($web)` checks if `$web` is set (exists as a php variable) and it is not `NULL`, but it could be blank (`$web = "";`).
- `&&` means `AND`.
- `$web != ""` check if `$web` (after checking if `$web` is set) is not blank (like `$web = "";`).

More info about `isset()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Your edited code will be:

```
<?php $web = types_render_field("value_website", array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";"));

if (isset($web) && $web != "") {
$strin = "<a target='_blank' href=\"".$web."\">Website</a>";
echo $strin;
}

?>
```

Your first code should be:

```
<div class="vright">

 <p><?php echo substr(get_the_content(),0,300); ?></p>

 <?php $web = types_render_field("value_website", array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";"));

 if(isset($web) && $web != "") {
 $strin = "<a target='_blank' href=\"".$web."\">Website</a>";
 }
 echo $strin; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank works. Could you please explain what you did in php function?